# Company name pattern Given by user should not match with some key words

Tags: sql, plsql

At the time of company registration given by user should not match list of names stored in the one table.

For example user input is:

```
MYINDIALTD
```

But `INDIA` is a restricted name stored in a table, so we need to raise an exception.

I tried `like`, but it matched exact only, but if company name just contained the word, it did not work.

Comment: What is your problem? Last sentence doesn't make any sense. Convert both names to uppercase and compare then? Or use ```String.equalsIgnoreCase(otherString)```

Comment: `Last sentence doesn't make any sense.` - Go easy on him/her. It is likely that he is not fluent in English.

Comment: If you realy interpret much into it i think he has a table with restricted names that may not occur in a user provided company name

Comment: in the name INDIA is keyword it may come in any pattern first,middle,last also.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return `true` if the input contains a restricted name, `false` otherwise:

```
select exists (
  select *
  from restricted_names
  where ? like concat('%', name, '%')
)
```

Obviously, you would substitute the `?` with your input, eg `MYINDIA LTD`.

If you need the reverse of the boolean result, `select not exists ...` instead.

Comment: select exists (
  SELECT COMPANY_NAME
  FROM COMPANYNAME_RESTRICT_LIST 
  WHERE COMPANY_NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', 'FijiINDIA', '%')
);

Comment: i try this but error showing can u give some example.

Comment: As per my answer, which says you substitute the `?` with your input, the final query would be: `select exists (select * from restricted_names where 'FijiINDIA' like concat('%', name, '%'))`. You gave no information about your schema, so I guessed the table name to be `restricted_names` and the column name to be `name` - you'll have to check those accordingly.